# How can I setup keycloak and Spring to use HTTPS when redirecting to login page

Tags: spring, https, cors, keycloak

I'm trying to reach a Spring Boot API hosted on a server with my Angular application, but I have some CORS issues.

[CORS Error in the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k0OCs.png)

[Redirection Flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U2y9f.png)

I tried several things, I added my URLs in both keycloak and Spring, and I think I found the origin of the problem but can't seems to resolve it.
I believe the problem comes from the fact that keycloak redirects to http://user-service.cubetech-app.fr/sso/login instead of the HTTPS version of that url. I read that when the browser detect a redirection on a different hostname it change the Origin header to null, and I think this is what creates the CORS error.

I don't know how to force HTTPS on the internal redirection.

For further informations, my spring backend and my keycloak server are hosted on my VPS, in a docker, and behind a traefik reverse-proxy that enables HTTPS with Let's Encrypt.

Answer (score 0):

Check the webOrigins value of the client you use in Keycloak.
Realm settings-> clients -> {your client}
[image]